# rsync include from list and delete from list

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I try to make a rsync with list of include and list of delete file.

My source dir looks like :

```
app/
    config/
        ignore.php
        include.php
```

My destination dir looks like :

```
app/
    delete.php
```

In include.txt file :

```
app/config/include.php
```

In delete.txt file :

```
app/delete.php
```

I have tried this command :

```
rsync -avz --include-from=include.txt --delete-excluded --exclude-from=delete.txt src/ dest/
```

The result is :

```
sending incremental file list
./
app/
deleting app/delete.php
app/config/
app/config/ignore.php
app/config/index.php
```

My problem is ignore.php was include because rsync probably ignore --include-from argument.

Need help plz :)

EDIT :

I replace include-from by files-from like that :

```
rsync -av --files-from=list --delete-excluded --exclude-from=delete src/ dest/
```

This command ignore app/config/include.php like I want BUT app/delete.php wasn't delete.

I try this :

```
rsync -av --delete-excluded --exclude-from=delete src/ dest/
```

app/delete.php is delete.

Why --files-from and --exclude-from doesn't work together ?

Comment: What does this have to do with `bash`?

Answer (score 2):

if your goal is to delete files from destination that are not present in source, and to ignore certain files in source from being copied to destination, then `delete.txt` is unnecessary when using the `--delete` option to mirror directories.
instead use an excludes file such as `exclude.txt` to ignore files in source that you don't want copied to destination.

file system before:

```
.
├── dest
│   └── app
│       └── delete.php
├── exclude.txt
├── src
│   └── app
│       └── config
│           ├── ignore.php
│           └── include.php
└── test.bash
```

exclude.txt:

```
app/config/ignore.php
```

test.bash:

```
rsync -av --exclude-from 'exclude.txt' --delete src/ dest/
```

after:

```
.
├── dest
│   └── app
│       └── config
│           └── include.php
├── exclude.txt
├── src
│   └── app
│       └── config
│           ├── ignore.php
│           └── include.php
└── test.bash
```